Suspend from keyboard
Using Ubuntu 22.04LTS and my "system" icon is missing and my keyboard "sleep" button does not work anymore when trying to do a "suspend" ever since the last system update.
Why does your update mess up things like that?
Gary

We don't provide updates... we are a community.

This is the Ubuntu system and they do provide updates to the system all the time. The last time a small update was carried out then this happened.  Can't suspend from the keyboard-------

"Why does your update mess up things like that?"   -we- don't provide updates. We at askubuntu are users of Ubuntu, just like you so we can not answer that specific question. If you want help from us focus on the problem itself: provide details regarding your system. And probably the result from xev when pressing the 'sleep' button . Maybe parts from dmesg that look relevant. If suspend does not work there will be an error logged somewhere :)

Am guessing Ubuntu is not reliable, thought this was their place to learn something.  I know nothing about using programming codes or whatever, it is just supposed to work.
When I had the computer set up to touch the "sleep" button on the keyboard when doing a "suspend" and now nothing happens after one of their regular updates. Will have to stop allowing updates as I don't have any idea why that wold have happened.  I don't get any error codes or anything like that.  Ubuntu needs to clean up their mess they made.
